# Почему при открытии карты, не подгружает начально значение?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, yandex-maps-api, vue3

Всем привет, проблема в следующем - при открытии страницы идет запрос на сервер, там получаем адрес с lat и lng и передаем их внутренние компоненты, к компоненте AddressAutocomplete так же выполняется поиск по названию адрес и отображаю маркером на карте location

если с бэка приходят lat и lng, то карта не прогружается до конца
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
если через f5 перезагружу страницу, то на карте все подгружается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а если в поле поиска меняю адрес , тогда вообще вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

чтобы здесь не писать кучу кода, вот можно посмотреть [здесь](https://github.com/aslero/ym/tree/main)